# Scala mutable.TreeMap "to" bug in 2.12.1?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Have spent some time on troubleshooting some code, came to curios bug with "to".  Did i miss something?

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val is = collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int, Int]()
is: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = TreeMap()
scala> is += 0 -> 9 += 70 -> 100
res0: is.type = TreeMap(0 -> 9, 70 -> 100)
scala> is.from(30)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = TreeMap(70 -> 100)
scala> is.to(30)
res2: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = TreeMap() // !!!!!

scala> val is2 = collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int, Int]()
is2: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map()
scala> val is3 = is2 + (0 -> 9) + (70 -> 100)
is3: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 9, 70 -> 100)
scala> is3.from(30)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map(70 -> 100)
scala> is3.to(30)
**res4: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 9)**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of `2.12.1`, corrected in `2.12.2`. It is probably related to [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10113).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be this one, last example in Jira issue is exactly what I got.

Comment: You're welcome! Please, mark the answer as accepted, if it satisfies you, so that other people may find it.